# How to resolve localhost:8443 to alias URL like "https://mydev.example" in my local Tomcat

Tags: ssl, tomcat, https, dns, hostname

I have successfully setup SSL in my local Tomcat at port 8443 with a certificate I generated locally for dev purposes. It is working fine.

In my `/etc/hosts` file I have entries:

```
127.0.0.1  mydev.example  mydevsecure.example
```

I can access my app by typing in:
`https://mydevsecure.example:8443/myApp/myPage.jsp`   [https]
OR 
`http://mydev.example/myApp/myPage.jsp`     [http]

What I want is to be able to type: `https://mydevsecure.example/myApp/myPage.jsp`

I want to lose typing the port number 8443 in my browser.

I can't specify port number in /etc/hosts file that I am aware of.

What other solutions are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by the following approach:

## Create self signed SSL certificate

Run the OpenSSL command to generate your private key and public certificate. Answer the questions and set a password as prompted.

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout mykey.pem -x509 -days 365 -out mycert.pem
```

## Install Apache

```
sudo yum install httpd
```

## Add SSL config in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /<path_to_ssl_certificate>/mycert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /<path_to_ssl_key>/mykey.pem
ServerName https:// mydev.example
ServerAlias https:// mydev.example
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

## Add the new secure URL alias in hosts file

127.0.0.1  mydev.example

## Start Tomcat and Apache

**I can now access my application through secure URL:**

https://mydev.example/myApp/myPage.jsp

Answer (score 0):

The default port for `https` is `443`. Typing `https://mydevsecure.example/myApp/myPage.jsp` into your browser, it will (try to) connect to the default `https` port `443`.

So you simply need to edit the `server.xml` file of your Apache Tomcat and find the SSL connector. Then change port `8443` to `443` and restart the Apache Tomcat.

**Edit**:

If your Tomcat cannot bind port 443 because it's not running as root, there are  multiple alternatives:

- Use [JSCV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html) to allow Tomcat bind port 443
- Use [other advanced unix](https://superuser.com/questions/710253/allow-non-root-process-to-bind-to-port-80-and-443) methods to allow tomcat binding to Port 443.
- Run Tomcat as root (**bad idea**...)
- Change Port back to 8443 and have a forwarder [redirect requests incoming on port 443 to 8443](https://serverfault.com/questions/749849/running-apache-tomcat-8-on-port-80).

Comment: On doing your suggested changes getting following error while tomcat startup:        org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase handleSubClassException
SEVERE: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-443]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
....

Comment: This is my tomcat connector details now :                            <Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
        keystoreFile="/home/userme/Desktop/SSL/MyCert.cert" keystorePass="***" sslProtocol="TLS" clientAuth="false"
    />

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full stack trace of that exception.

Comment: This error is caused when I acted according to your suggestion and is not part of the original question @Selaron

Comment: The cause of the error is mentioned within the stack trace and mandatory to know in order to find a solution for your problem.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, but I am unable to paste the stack trace in comments section due to 600 characters limit in comments text. Any other way I can share it with you?

Comment: [ask] has a link to [How to ask the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) which states: "Well, what did you expect it to do? What are you trying to accomplish? What have you already tried? What happened in those attempts?" - therefore editing your question and adding this yet failed attempt does not seem to be a bad idea and might help solve it.

Comment: @Ani guessing Tomcat cannot bind to port 443 I edited my answer and added possibly helpful hints/links.

Comment: Thanks @Selaron for your inputs. Yes you are correct in your assumption I suppose, as I looked up and found similar solutions in net. In this scenario, a way might be to use Apache--> enable SSL in Apache and configure it to forward those request to Tomcat (with Tomcat not running SSL obviously).